# Structure Array arguments in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I'm pretty new to C and am taking a class right now and having difficulty with a project. We have a structure in this project called a Symbol. We also have a structure in this project called a Node. Nodes have an array of Symbols. All I'm trying to do is set the property Node.symbols to another array of symbols like so:

```
   int max = 256;
   Symbol symbols[max];
   Node node1;
   node1.syms = symbols;
```

Error: incompatibles types when comparing 'struct Symbol[256]' from type 'Struct Symbol *'

I don't really understand why it thinks that symbols is a pointer, when it seems like an array of symbols to me. This might be really obvious but I haven't been able to fix it.

Comment: that means `syms` is declared as `struct Symbol[256]`. you need to copy over one by one. FYI, `symbols` is pointer too. if you don't understand this, it's better for you to review your textbook first.

Comment: symbols is not a pointer it is an array, but in C arrays are very close to pointers. can you post here how Node is defined? You can only do that assignment  if node1.syms was a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the assignment operator `=` for arrays. You either have to use a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
{
    node1.syms[i] = symbols[i];
}
```

or use memcpy:

```
memcpy(node1.syms, symbols, max * sizeof(symbols[0]));
```

BTW, `max` is a bad name to use for an array dimension (or anything else for that matter), since it clashes with the name of the `max()` function/macro.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't realize that was a difference in C and the error was written in such a way that through me off. Looks like I still have a lot to learn in basic C, I appreciate the help

Comment: What about a preprocessor macro for MAX ?

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the definition of `Node` and `Symbol` but I suppose that `Node.syms` is an array. In this case the problem is that in line `node1.syms = symbols;` you try to change the the `sysm` member of `Node` struct but it is a constant varible (every array is constant, you can not change its location).

You have to possibilities.

1.) You copy the elements from the destination array to `syms` array:

```
int numelem = 256;
for (int i = 0; i < numelem; i++)
{
    node1.syms[i] = symbols[i];
}
```

But it is very important to find out the perfect value of `numelem` variable. Namely it is nowhere checked that the `node1.syms` and `symbols` arrays have the same number of elements. If their lengths are not equal you can overrun on one of them addressing illegal memory areas. Another possible disadvantege is that in all the `Node` elements the `syms` array will have the same number of elements, you can change it only in compile time.

2.) You change the definition if `Node` structure:

```
struct Node {
   //...
   struct Symbol *syms;
   //...
}
```

It this case your code will be complied and arrays `node1.syms` will be pointed to the array `symbol` and you do not have to take care about the length of the arrays. But it is important that in this case you will have only one array in the memory! So, you have to take into account that arrays are normally allocated on stack which means that after exiting from a method where the array was created the memory space of array will be freed as well. If you create `node1` also it the method (as in your example) it is fine. But if you create `node1` as a global variable than `symbols` array has to be global as well. In general we can say that both variable have to create in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

symbols is a pointer. It is the head of the array symbols[256] and is of type Symbol*. Dereferencing by [] then adds sizeof(Symbol) for each increment, e.g. symbols[3] references the 4th element in the array at adress symbols+3*sizeof(Symbols)

Using [] of a pointer is safer than doing explicit pointer arithmetics